# How to change default tooltip from main menu for wm.url_open

Tags: python, interface

I used this python script to add an easy way to open the explorer to the menu.
How can I change the default tooltip?
Thank you.

```
import bpy

def menu_func(self, context):
    '''Open explorer in windows systems'''
    self.layout.operator(
            "wm.url_open", text="Open explorer", icon='FILE_FOLDER').url = "C:/"
def register():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_help.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_help.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: which tooltip? maybe a screenshot for context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a wrapper for this `ops` function, so that you can define the tooltip in the wrapper

```
import bpy

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
            OpenOperator.bl_idname, text="Open explorer", icon='FILE_FOLDER')

class OpenOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Open explorer in windows systems"""
    bl_idname = "wm.open_explorer"
    bl_label = "Open explorer"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.wm.url_open(url="C:/")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OpenOperator)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_help.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OpenOperator)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_help.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: a wrapper, yes this is the solution, thank you.